# F# - Convert PPM Image to Greyscale

Tags: image, f#, grayscale, ppm

I am new to F# and was wondering if there is a way to convert an image in ppm to grayscale using F#?

Comment: Probably. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Questions looking for libraries and other off-site resources are off-topic… Nevertheless: have a look at [ImageSharp](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Pbm.PbmDecoder.html)

Comment: Indeed it is a .NET level problem than F#. So use a specific NuGet